# How to set a background color when body size is smaller than viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this animation in the body that makes the body shrinks to a much smaller size than viewport area. But when the body animation happens rest of the viewport background color appear white. I can't control that color and what is that area? Is it root or html? I tried to set a background-color property to root and html but it makes the body animation hidden/missing. I have a dark/black body background set after the animation. But during the body animation the rest of the background appear white and I need to change that to black.

CSS

```
body 
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white, white, #98AEC4, white, #98AEC4, white, white) fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center; 
    background-size: 85% 2%; 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 615px) and (orientation: portrait)
{
body 
{
    background-size: 85% 2%;
    animation: mooveme 0.4s;
}
}
@keyframes mooveme
{
    from
    {
        background-size: 85% 2%;
    }
    to
    {
        background-size: 45% 2%;
    }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
setInterval(function() 
{      
     document.body.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";  
    
}, 400);
```

Adding `html { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1); }` changes the first 400 ms to a black background but the body animation doesn't work. Only forcing chrome to dark mode under (chrome://flags/) can make the rest of the background black with the desired body animation. What is going on? How can I fix both?

Comment: I don’t see anywhere where you are changing the body size, only the background size. Have I missed something? And why are you using WebKit on the background image? Also iOS has trouble with background attachment fixed. See caniuse.

Comment: You're right I'm changing body background size. Without that -webkit-linear-gradient() fixed body background gradient doesn't work. And in ios it doesn't look right.

Comment: You have a non-standard 'left' in your linear-gradient. If you put 'to left' then the -webkit- is not needed and the declaration will be more standard. And it doesnt look right on ios because of the fixed.

Comment: With the new solution the standard one is working again without that fixed at the end. Thanks for the tip ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing the size of the body at all - only the size of part of its overall background.

So to have the rest of the screen black you can just set its background color, no need to invoke JS to do that at the end of the animation, you need it throughout.

Note also that IOS has a problem with fixed attachment in some versions so this has been removed.

```css
body 
{
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white, white, #98AEC4, white, #98AEC4, white, white);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center; 
    background-size: 85% 2%; 
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:black;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 615px) and (orientation: portrait)
{
body 
{
    background-size: 85% 2%;
    animation: mooveme 0.4s;
}
}
@keyframes mooveme
{
    from
    {
        background-size: 85% 2%;
    }
    to
    {
        background-size: 45% 2%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your approach worked and you are damn right about the logic. I need to add background-attachment: fixed; to make the animation appear at any scroll position. I don't have ios device. I have doubt that setting height width unit to vw and vh will not look right on IOS. Do you think 100vh and 100vw will work on ios ..?

Comment: To get round the IOS fixed problem in the past I've had to introduce another element (or a pseudo one) which is fixed and has the required background.

Comment: Allso I would remove the webkit and use 'to left' in the linear-gradient as being more standard.

Comment: Yeah I'm using the more standard one now.

Answer (score 1):

use !important keyword for background change or set color in aninamtion too

```
body 
{
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white, white, #98AEC4, white, #98AEC4, white, white);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center; 
    background-size: 85% 2%; 
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:black !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 615px) and (orientation: portrait)
{
body 
{
    background-size: 85% 2%;
    animation: mooveme 0.4s;
}
}
@keyframes mooveme
{
    from
    {
        background-size: 85% 2%;
    }
    to
    {
        background-size: 45% 2%;
    }
}
```

```
body 
{
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white, white, #98AEC4, white, #98AEC4, white, white);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center; 
    background-size: 85% 2%; 
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color:black !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 615px) and (orientation: portrait)
{
body 
{
    background-size: 85% 2%;
    animation: mooveme 0.4s;
}
}
@keyframes mooveme
{
    from
    {
        background-size: 85% 2%;
        backgroun-color: black;
    }
    to
    {
        background-size: 45% 2%;
        backgroun-color: black;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the background of the root element - just confirming you used the pseudo selector `:`?

```css
/* Selects the root element of the document:
   <html> in the case of HTML */
:root {
  background: yellow;
}
```

That said, sounds like there are some anomalies that crop up if you set the background of both the body and html elements, where if you set the `<html>` background then the `<body>` element behaves just like a regular `<div>` element, that is, it's height will be determined by it's content.

https://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root

Comment: yeah I tried that `:root { background: black; }` but it does the same thing as `html { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1); }` and the body animation doesn't work. I need both to work. Thanks for the answer ...

Comment: Adding height: 100vh; to the body tag makes both work but this solution isn't working on mobile browsers. Why?